# Run JS File in Webbrowser when the site loads

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to run a ".js" file on the webbrowser when the site loads, but I don't have a clue how to do it, would I have to apply to the `<head>` of the site before it loads?

**Example**:

```
On site load...

webbrowser load: "file.js"

Run
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<script src="PATH_OF_SCRIPT"></script>` after the `<html>` tag.

So, assuming your `file.js` is in the same directory as your HTML file, this should be `<script src="file.js"></script>`